# a field named '' on field list is ambiguous

Tags: asp.net, mysql

```
string sql = @"
 SELECT 
       sit.descricao       AS situacao, 
       pri.prioridade      AS prioridade, 
       usr.nome            AS responsavel, 
       ch.previsao_termino AS previsao, 
       ch.descricao        AS descricao, 
       clb.clube, 
       proj.descricao      AS projeto, 
       func.descricao      AS funcionalidade 
FROM   
       chamados AS ch 
LEFT JOIN 
       prioridades AS pri 
ON 
       ch.prioridade = pri.id 
INNER JOIN 
       situacoes AS sit 
ON 
       ch.situacao = sit.id 
LEFT JOIN 
       usuarios AS usr 
ON 
       ch.responsavel = usr.id 
INNER JOIN 
       clubes AS clb 
ON 
       ch.clube = clb.id 
INNER JOIN 
       projetos AS proj 
ON 
       ch.projeto = proj.id 
INNER JOIN 
       funcionalidades AS func 
ON 
      ch.funcionalidade = func.id 
WHERE  
      ch.id = @id";


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@id", MySqlDbType.Int32)).Value = _ch.ID;
DataSet retorno = _dal.Consultar(cmd);
return retorno;
```

When it returns it is NOT EMPTY, but when I to this:

```
GridView1.DataSource(retorno);
GridView1.DataBind(); //Here Fires the error.
```

It fires the error that is on the title. I read a lot of others topics already open here, but I can't see where it is ambiguous. Is my query ? Or maybe something else... It was working then I debbuged again, and the error fired...

The error:

```
a field named 'prioridade' on field list is ambiguous
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in query. Check data set inside the data set there will be datatable see the columns of the data table and check do you have multiple columns with the name prioridade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `chamados` and `prioridades` tables have a field named `prioridade`. Therefore you cannot use that field name as an alias in your `SELECT`-statement.

Try `pri.prioridade      AS prioridad` or something like that.

Comment: Even I'm using diferent sufix ? Like: Chamados AS ch  ch.prioridade | prioridades AS pri pri.prioridade. ??]

Comment: Yes, even then. When reffering to `prioridades`, mysql doesn't know whether you mean the alias, the one in the `chamados`-table or the `prioridades`-table.